desktop (and mouse) freezes seemingly randomly, closing lid won't suspend until after a minute
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Framework laptop, the desktop has been freezing recently (maybe for about a week).
Laptop specs:

Ubuntu version: 22.04
Linux kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic x86_64
CPU: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2
RAM: 64 GB

It happened five times this morning, for example, and once this evening.
When the freezing happens, I note the time and I close my laptop lid. The display does not turn off like normal, and the laptop does not suspend. I used to force reboot the laptop when it would freeeze, but recently I have noticed if I keep closing and opening the lid, after about a minute the freezing stops and the laptop finally suspends and I am able to login again and the freezing has ceased.
During this freezed state the inability to suspend results in this log message in the syslog:
Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7

This allows me to pinpoint what was going on just before.
So far nothing seems consistent among messages happening before the freezes in /var/log/syslog.
Was hoping someone could suggest what other logs to check, or what other diagnostics to pursue to help me narrow down and solve the problem.
Of course I have done the typical things like running sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.
Thanks so much!
